# Viewing raw XML build log on CruiseControl.NET under IIS7 - 404

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, cruisecontrol.net

I've installed CruiseControl.NET 1.5 (CTP) on a Windows 2008 server with IIS7.

The installer doesn't create a virtual directory for the ccnet dashboard. No biggie, configured that manually, and also changed the AppPool to be Classic as opposed to Integrated Pipeline mode.

The web dashboard displays and generally works fine (I can view the projects and force builds etc.), but when I want to view the raw XML log file, a URL that ends with something like `build/log20100114095622.xml/XmlBuildLog.xml`, I get a 404 error, and it seems that IIS is trying to route the .XML file through IIS7's StaticFile handler.

I have tried creating custom script map (for just the ccnet app obviously) for ASPNET_ISAPI that maps to *.xml, restarted IIS, but I'm still getting the same error.

Would appreciate if someone could shed any light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Looks like I added the script mapping for .xml on the 32-bit version of the ASPNET_ISAPI DLL, which was the reason it wasn't invoked.

Just added a *.xml script map for the 64-bit version, at path `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`, and it now works a treat.